# Blank page apply.cgi during selenium webdriver automation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a router configuration using selenium webdriver. Below is the html of the router page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="">
   <head>
   <body onunload="return unload_body();" onload="initial();">
      <div id="TopBanner">
      <div id="Loading" class="popup_bg">
      <div id="hiddenMask" class="popup_bg">
      <iframe id="hidden_frame" height="0" frameborder="0" width="0" name="hidden_frame">
      <form target="hidden_frame" action="/start_apply2.htm" name="autochannelform" method="post">
      <form target="hidden_frame" action="/start_apply2.htm" name="form" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" value="RT-N66U" name="productid">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wan_route_x">
         <input type="hidden" value="1" name="wan_nat_x">
         <input type="hidden" value="Advanced_Wireless_Content.asp" name="current_page">
         <input type="hidden" value="Advanced_Wireless_Content.asp" name="next_page">
         <input type="hidden" value="0" name="modified">
         <input type="hidden" value="apply_new" name="action_mode">
         <input type="hidden" value="restart_wireless" name="action_script">
         <input type="hidden" value="10" name="action_wait">
         <input id="preferred_lang" type="hidden" value="EN" name="preferred_lang">
         <input type="hidden" disabled="" value="US" name="wl_country_code">
         <input type="hidden" value="3.0.0.4" name="firmver">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wps_mode">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wps_config_state">
         <input type="hidden" disabled="" value="" name="wlc_ure_ssid_org">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_key1_org">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_key2_org">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_key3_org">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_key4_org">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_phrase_x_org">
         <input type="hidden" readonly="1" value="" name="x_RegulatoryDomain" size="15" maxlength="15">
         <input type="hidden" value="off" name="wl_gmode_protection">
         <input type="hidden" value="on" name="wl_wme">
         <input type="hidden" value="0" name="wl_mode_x">
         <input type="hidden" value="-1" name="wl_nmode">
         <input type="hidden" value="1" name="wl_nmode_x_orig">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_nctrlsb_old">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_key_type">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_channel_orig">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="wl_chanspec">
         <input type="hidden" value="0" name="wl_wep_x_orig">
         <input type="hidden" value="0" name="wl_optimizexbox">
         <input type="hidden" value="-1" name="wl_subunit">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="acs_dfs">
         <input type="hidden" value="0" name="acs_band1">
         <table class="content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td width="17"> </td>
                  <td width="202" valign="top">
                  <td valign="top">
                     <div id="tabMenu" class="submenuBlock">
                     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" width="98%">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td align="left" valign="top">
                                 <table id="FormTitle" class="FormTitle_firefox" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" width="760px" style="height: 838px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td bgcolor="#4D595D" valign="top">
                                             <div> </div>
                                             <div class="formfonttitle">Wireless - General</div>
                                             <div style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px">
                                             <div class="formfontdesc">Set up the wireless related information below.</div>
                                             <table id="WLgeneral" class="FormTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" align="center" width="99%">
                                                <tbody>
                                                   <tr id="wl_unit_field">
                                                      <th>Frequency</th>
                                                      <td>
                                                         <select class="input_option" onchange="_change_wl_unit(this.value);" name="wl_unit">
                                                            <option class="content_input_fd" selected="" value="0">2.4GHz</option>
                                                            <option class="content_input_fd" value="1">5GHz</option>
                                                         </select>
                                                      </td>
                                                   </tr>
                                                   <tr>
                                                   <tr>
                                                   <tr>
                                                   <tr id="wl_bw_field">
                                                   <tr>
                                                   <tr id="wl_nctrlsb_field">
                                                   <tr>
                                                   <tr>
                                                   <tr>
                                                   <tr style="display: none;">
                                                   <tr style="display: none;">
                                                   <tr style="display: none;">
                                                   <tr style="display: none;">
                                                   <tr style="display: none;">
                                                   <tr style="display: none;">
                                                   <tr style="display: none;">
                                                   <tr style="display:none">
                                                   <tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                             </table>
                                             <div class="apply_gen">
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </td>
                  <td align="center" width="10" valign="top"></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <div id="footer">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to select "5GHz" option from "Frequency" drop down box. Below is the code which is doing this:

```
self.browser_driver.get(self.base_url)
self.browser_driver.find_element_by_id("option_str1").click()
time.sleep(1)
                     Select(self.browser_driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[name=\"wl_unit\"]")).select_by_visible_text("5GHz")
time.sleep(10)

self.browser_driver.close()
```

But as soon as the `5GHz` option is selected from drop down menu I get blank page with address `router_ip/apply.cgi`. I see following message on this webpage.

> The "router_ip" page isn’t working
>   "router_ip" didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

How do I get rid of this issue. I don't get this issue during manual configuration of the router.

Comment: hmmm, it's as if the on_change attribute on that select element is being ignored...it looks like there's a method there that's suppose to use the chosen value as an argument, and the error message is implying that it wasn't set.

Comment: This is the html of apply button which I click after selecting the value from drop down box:
<div class="apply_gen">
<input id="applyButton" class="button_gen" type="button" onclick="applyRule();" value="Apply">
</div>

but I could not find applyRule() function anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was prepending router credentials to the base_url in python script which was causing issue on page refresh. Page refresh was happening after option was getting selected from drop down menu and script was not able to open the authentication url again. Now I open base_url(without credentials) after logging into the router with authentication url in the same session. Now following code is working:

```
self.base_url = "http://"+server_ip+"/"
self.auth_url = "http://" + "login" + ":" + "password" + "@" +server_ip+"/"
self.browser_driver.get(self.auth_url)
self.browser_driver.get(self.base_url)
self.browser_driver.find_element_by_id("option_str1").click()
time.sleep(1)
Select(self.browser_driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[name=\"wl_unit\"]")).select_by_visible_text("5GHz")
time.sleep(10)
self.browser_driver.close()
```